# Dafny linear search

Tags: dafny

When working on a basic linear search I encountered an error with my Valid() predicate. It seems to only work when I uncomment the additional ensures statements on the constructor and the data method. That is, when I am very explicit about the contents.

I'm also having trouble with the postcondition of my search when the item isn't found.

Any suggestions on how to resolve these?

```
  class Search{
    ghost var Contents: set<int>;
    var a : array<int>;

    predicate Valid()
        reads this, a;
    {
        a != null &&
        a.Length > 0 &&

        Contents == set x | 0 <= x < a.Length :: a[x]
    }

    constructor ()
        ensures a != null;
        ensures a.Length == 4;
        //ensures a[0] == 0;
        ensures Valid();
    {
        a := new int[4](_ => 0);
        Contents := {0};
        new;
    }

    method data()
        modifies this, a;
        requires Valid();
        requires a != null;
        requires a.Length == 4;
        ensures a != null;
        ensures a.Length == 4;
        // ensures a[0] == 0;
        // ensures a[1] == 1;
        // ensures a[2] == 2;
        // ensures a[3] == 3;
        ensures Valid();
    {
        a[0] := 0;
        a[1] := 1;
        a[2] := 2;
        a[3] := 3;
        Contents := {0, 1, 2, 3};
    }

    method search(e: int) returns (r: bool)
        modifies this, a;
        requires Valid();
        ensures Valid();
        ensures r == (e in Contents)
        ensures r == exists i: int :: 0 <= i < a.Length && a[i] == e
    {
        var length := a.Length - 1;

        while (length >= 0)
            decreases length;
        {
            var removed := a[length];
            if (e == removed)
            {
                return true;
            }
            length := length - 1;
        }
        return false;
    }
  }


method Main()
{
    var s := new Search();
    s.data();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several orthogonal issues going on here.

First, you have noticed that Dafny is reluctant to reason about the part of `Valid` that describes `Contents`. This is a common problem when reasoning about sets in Dafny. Essentially, the only way Dafny will ever "notice" that something is a member of the set `set x | 0 <= x < a.Length :: a[x]` is if it already has the expression `a[x]` lying around somewhere. Your solution of including extra postconditions works because it mentions a lot of expressions of the form `a[x]`. Another solution is to include those facts as assertions instead of postconditions:

```
// in data()
assert a[0] == 0;
assert a[1] == 1;
assert a[2] == 2;
assert a[3] == 3;
```

Second, Dafny cannot show your `search` procedure satisfies its postcondition. You need a loop invariant to keep track of the progress of the search. See the [guide](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial/Guide) for more information about how to design loop invariants.

Third, Dafny reports a problem with your `Main` about modifies clauses. You can fix this by adding a postcondition `fresh(a)` to the `constructor`. The problem here is that the `data` method claims to modify `a`, but Dafny can't tell if `a` is visible from the caller.